# Give an example for $A,B,C$ sets and for $\varrho, \sigma$ mappings:

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For $A,B,C$ sets, let be $\varrho: A \rightarrow B$ $\sigma:B \rightarrow C$

(1) $\rho$ injective but, $ \rho \sigma$ not injective

(2) $\sigma$ surjective, but $ \rho \sigma$ not surjective

(3) $\rho$ not surjective, and $\sigma$ not injective, but  $ \rho \sigma$ is bijective

I know that,

surjective: $ \varrho:A \rightarrow B$ if $(\forall b \in B)(\exists a \in A)(a \varrho =b) $

injective: $ \varrho: A \rightarrow B$ if $( \forall a_{1},a_{2} \in A)(a_{1} \varrho =a_{2} \implies a_{1}=a_{2})$

I know of course injective and surjective functions, but how does it work for sets, and how does the multiplication work?

Comment: The 'multiplication' of functions is composition

Answer (score 1):

The 'multiplication' you refer to is composition.

That is the function $ \rho \sigma$ is a function $\rho \sigma : A \rightarrow C$ defined as: $ \rho \sigma (x) = \rho(\sigma(x))$

E.g. if $\sigma(1) = 2$ and $\rho(2) = 3$, then $ \rho \sigma (1) = \rho(\sigma(1)) = \rho(2)= 3$

Here is answer to 1):

1) Let $A = \{ 1,2\}$, $B = \{ 3,4\}$, $C = \{ 5 \}$

and define $ \rho(1) = 3$, $ \rho(2) = 4$, and $\sigma(3)=\sigma(4)=5$

Do you see how $\rho$ is injective? And how $\rho \sigma$ is not?

Do something similar for 2) and 3): just draw 3 circles for A,B, and C, and put some objects inside, and draw some arrows (the function mappings) to try to satisfy what they are looking for.